# What is wrong with the compute shader so that it works much slower than the vertex-fragment pipeline?

Tags: c++, performance, opengl, shader, compute-shader

Recently I was working on a simple 3d engine, which has multilayered rendering. In particular it makes 3 draw calls with outputs into 3 different textures and then blends all together into the final texture (that later goes to the screen).

The rendering is just fine. It uses independent shader programs and all the textures have correct data after that.

The first version of the blender program was using a single compute shader that just walks over the pixels of the input textures and blends to respective output texture pixel:

```
// in .cpp:
    glBindImageTexture(0, tex[0], 0, GL_FALSE, 0,  GL_READ_ONLY, GL_RGBA32F);
    glBindImageTexture(1, tex[1], 0, GL_FALSE, 0,  GL_READ_ONLY, GL_RGBA32F);
    glBindImageTexture(2, tex[2], 0, GL_FALSE, 0,  GL_READ_ONLY, GL_RGBA32F);
    glBindImageTexture(3, finTex, 0, GL_FALSE, 0,  WRITR_ONLY, GL_RGBA32F);

    blenderProgram->use();

    glUniform4f(0, 1., 0., 0., 1.); // highlight color
    glUniform4f(1, 0., 0., 0., 0.); // background color

    int x = ceil(width / 32.), y = ceil(height / 32.);
    glDispatchCompute(x, y, 1);

    glMemoryBarrier(GL_SHADER_IMAGE_ACCESS_BARRIER_BIT);       

// in shader:
    #version 430 core

    layout( local_size_x = 32, local_size_y = 32 ) in;

    layout( location = 0 ) uniform vec4 highlight;
    layout( location = 1 ) uniform vec4 background;

    layout(binding = 0, rgba32f) uniform readonly image2D src1;
    layout(binding = 1, rgba32f) uniform readonly image2D src2;
    layout(binding = 2, rgba32f) uniform readonly image2D src3;
    layout(binding = 3, rgba32f) uniform writeonly image2D dst;

    void main()
    {
        ivec2 pos = ivec2(gl_GlobalInvocationID.xy);

        vec4 col1 = imageLoad(src1, pos);
        vec4 col2 = imageLoad(src2, pos);
        vec4 col3 = imageLoad(src3, pos);

        vec4 res = background;

        // mix scr1, scr2, scr3, highlight into res
        ...

        imageStore(dst, pos, res);
    }
```

However, despite the simplicity this caused entire UI to lag or even freeze.

The second version was actually the same blending procedure, but invoked from fragment shader while just rendering a full-screen quad:

```
// in .cpp:
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, blenderFBO);

    GLuint buffers[] = { GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 };
    glDrawBuffers(1, buffers);

    glBindImageTexture(0, tex[0], 0, GL_FALSE, 0,  GL_READ_ONLY, GL_RGBA32F);
    glBindImageTexture(1, tex[1], 0, GL_FALSE, 0,  GL_READ_ONLY, GL_RGBA32F);
    glBindImageTexture(2, tex[2], 0, GL_FALSE, 0,  GL_READ_ONLY, GL_RGBA32F);

    blenderProgram1->use();

    glUniform4f(0, 1., 0., 0., 1.); // highlight color
    glUniform4f(1, 0., 0., 0., 0.); // background color

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex2f(-1, -1);
    glVertex2f(1, -1);
    glVertex2f(1, 1);
    glVertex2f(-1, 1);
    glEnd();

// vertex shader:
    #version 430 core

    in vec2 a_position;

    void main()
    {
        gl_Position = vec4(a_position, 0.0, 1.0);
    }

// fragment shader:
    #version 430 core

    layout( location = 0 ) uniform vec4 highlight;
    layout( location = 1 ) uniform vec4 background;

    layout(binding = 0, rgba32f) uniform readonly image2D src1;
    layout(binding = 1, rgba32f) uniform readonly image2D src2;
    layout(binding = 2, rgba32f) uniform readonly image2D src3;

    layout(location = 0) out vec4 dst;

    void main()
    {
        ivec2 pos = ivec2( gl_FragCoord.xy );

        vec4 col1 = imageLoad(src1, pos);
        vec4 col2 = imageLoad(src2, pos);
        vec4 col3 = imageLoad(src3, pos);

        vec4 res = background;

        // the same mix of col1, col2, col3 and highlight into res
        ...

        dst = res3;
    }
```

This time everything worked exactly as expected.

The difference in performance was tremendous. PCs with gaming graphic cards started lagging in case of compute shaders, but the laptops had the entire operating system UI frozen.

The question is: why is this compute shader so much slower than the vertex-fragment pair? In deed it should have been faster due to avoiding the interpolation steps, samples build process and other unused stuff of the standard rendering pipeline. What do I miss in here?

Comment: What OS are you using, what GPU, what driver version do you have installed?

Comment: Also, maybe I misunderstand, but should glMemoryBarrier perhaps be _before_ glDispatchCompute?

Comment: @Andrea   I tested the code on Linux mint, Ubuntu and Windows; drivers versions vary but all support 430+ shaders (if need full set of drivers info - I may gather it); glMemoryBarrier actually seems to be optional it this case, it was used just to be sure that the textures (regardless of content) are ready to be copied to screen texture.

Comment: Hmm. And the code omitted with “...” was identical in both versions?

Comment: I tried several variations, but generally it was like

res = mix( mix( mix( res, src1, src1.a ), src2, src2.a ), src3, src3.a );

Any way the resulting image was correct - as was expected.